# How to create simple covariance in Julia on a matrix

Tags: julia

Using Julia 0.5.  Given:

```
Supertech = [-.2 .1 .3 .5];
Slowpoke = [.05 .2 -.12 .09];
```

How in the world can I get a covariance.  In Excel I just say

```
=covariance.p(Supertech,Slowpoke)
```

and it gives me the correct answer of `-0.004875`

For the life of me I can't figure out how to get this to work using `StatsBase.cov()`

I've tried putting this into a matrix like:

```
X = [Supertech; Slowpoke]'
```

which gives me a nice:

```
4×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 -0.2   0.05
  0.1   0.2 
  0.3  -0.12
  0.5   0.09
```

but I can't get this simple thing to work.  I keep coming up with dimension mismatches when I try to use the WeightedVector type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax `[-.2 .1 .3 .5]` doesn't create a vector, it creates a one-row matrix. The [`cov` function](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Statistics/#Statistics.cov) is actually defined in base Julia, but it requires vectors. So you simply need to use the syntax with commas to create vectors in the first place (`[-.2, .1, .3, .5]`), or you can use the `vec` function to reshape the matrix to a one-dimensional vector. It also uses the ["corrected" covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction) by default, whereas Excel is using the "uncorrected" covariance.  You can use the third argument to specify that you don't want this correction.

```
julia> cov(vec(Supertech), vec(Slowpoke))
-0.0065

julia> cov(vec(Supertech), vec(Slowpoke), false)
-0.004875
```

Comment: Thanks!  Now...Is there a way to do this in a vectorized manner so that, given an matrix of A=n vectors, I can just say `cov(A,false)` and get a vector or 1-dimensional array back of all of the covariances?

Comment: Yes, but it'll return a [covariance matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix).  E.g., with a three-column matrix, it'll return a 3x3 matrix, where the element at `(i,j)` is the covariance between column `i` and `j`.

Comment: Ok, I'm still confused.  Here is a modified version of the code above, this time with a loop effort to calc the covariance which works:`using StatsBase
Supertech = [-.2; .1; .3; .5];
Slowpoke = [.05; .2; -.12; .09];
X = reshape([Supertech; Slowpoke],4,2)
mlen = size(X)[1]
means = mean_and_cov(X)[1]
covtmp = ones(mlen)
means[1]

for i=1:mlen
    for j=1:rank(X)
        covtmp[i] =  covtmp[i] * (X[i,j]  - means[j]);
    end
end
mycov = sum(covtmp)/mlen;
println("Correct covariance of matrix X = ",mycov)
println("Whereas cov(X) = ",cov(X))`

Comment: can you provide a solution based on the original data posted?

Comment: I'd just ask a new question about covariance of many vectors.